# gtable_add_grob(): linesGrob() not displayed

Tags: r, r-grid, gtable

Why are the lines (via `linesGrob`) not drawn in the following plot?

```
require(gtable)
base <- gtable(widths=unit(rep(1, 2), "null"),
               heights=unit(rep(1, 3), "null"))
grid.newpage()
g <- 1
for(i in 1:3) {
    for(j in 1:2) {
        base <- gtable_add_grob(base,
                                grobs=list(linesGrob(x=1:4, y=4:1),
                                           rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="#FF0000")),
                                           textGrob(label=g)), i, j, name=1:3)
        g <- g+1
    }
}
grid.draw(base)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two reasons:

- the coordinates fall outside the viewport
- the rectGrob is drawn on top and masks it

---

```
require(gtable)
# let's fix this name before it's too late
gtable_add_grobs <- gtable_add_grob

base <- gtable(widths=unit(rep(1, 2), "null"),
               heights=unit(rep(1, 3), "null"))
grid.newpage()
g <- 1
for(i in 1:3) {
    for(j in 1:2) {
        base <- gtable_add_grobs(base,
                                grobs=list(rectGrob(gp=gpar(fill="#FF0000")),
                                           linesGrob(x=1:4, y=4:1, def="native", 
                                                     vp=dataViewport(1:4, 1:4)),
                                           textGrob(label=g)), i, j, name=1:3)
        g <- g+1
    }
}
grid.draw(base)
```

---

*Note* `gtable_add_grobs` is vectorised, which means you shouldn't have to use for loops, ideally. It's easier if you group all the grobs together first, for a given cell, in a gTree. Here's a simplified version,

```
library(gtable)

g <- gtable(widths = unit(c(1,1), "null"),
            heights = unit(c(1,1), "null"))


cell <- function(ii)
  grobTree(rectGrob(), 
           linesGrob(1:4, 1:4, default.units="native"), 
           textGrob(ii),
           vp=dataViewport(c(1,4), c(1,4)))

gl <- lapply(1:4, cell)

xy <- expand.grid(1:2, 1:2)

g <- gtable_add_grobs(g, gl, 
                      l=xy[,1],
                      r=xy[,1],
                      t=xy[,2],
                      b=xy[,2])


grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Comment: Thanks, Baptiste. The 2nd reason is clear, but the first (?). All viewports have their default `NULL` value, so shouldn't the points be just drawn in corresponding rectangle as is in the case a new page is opened. This is something I don't really understand yet... why (and how) do I have to specify that... In 'classical' grid, I would push the viewport and then it would just work.

Comment: each cell of the gtable has a viewport, and when you draw a grob in it you need to make sure the coordinates fit within the viewport. A basic example is `grid.newpage(); grid.lines(x=1:4, y=4:1, default.units = "npc")`: it draws nothing, because `1:4` are interpreted as normalised coordinates, running from 0 to 1. You need either to rescale your data, or specify a viewport and work with "native" coordinates.

Comment: thanks for the answer, Baptiste. The solution with rescaling the data also works (but is less intuitive/natural).

Comment: @MariusHofert I've added a more natural version to add multiple grobs in one go, without for loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Baptiste, I'll have a closer look at it. Does summarizing certain parts in a `gTree` first avoid having to use different names for all grobs in `gTree`? The reason why I am asking is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18028920/how-to-use-gtable-add-grob-does-not-add where the suggested solution uses different names for each `rectGrob`, `textGrob`... which is quite tedious. I'd rather have one name such as "panel" for all `rectGrob`, `textGrob`, and `lineGrob` together.

Comment: I believe so, but I'm not sure; I don't understand the naming requirements either.